# remote "desktop mouse" with Magic trackpad emulator for iPad or Mac Book

Tags: ipad, remote-desktop, remote-control, magic-trackpad, mouse

I would like to control my desktop Mac with a Magic trackpad or Magic mouse "emulation".

I have an iPad and an Macbook Air too. So my questions are:

There are some iPad App to emulate a Magic Trackpad to control my desktop Mac?
There's any way to connect my Air trackpad to the desktop Mac?
Any idea to make it possible maybe with Apple Remote Desktop or any other tool?

Thanks

EDIT: I just found this one, looks very good!
http://www.bttremote.com

Comment: Hi, great to hear you found a solution. Could you please post it as an answer, explain what it does and check it as the accepted solution? This keeps the site organised and in the "question&answer" style.

Answer (score 1):

## Software KVM

You might want to take a look at these two additional packages - they don't support iPad but will allow you to use your Air in conjunction with your desktop.

- **Synergy** Which used to be free - and can still be downloaded for free if you pull a nightly build
- **ShareMouse** which costs maybe $50 or so

Both are virtual KVM software that allow multiple computers to share a single (or multiple) keyboard mice

[ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com) is the more advanced software and it will let you use the Mouse/Keyboard from all connected computers - as well as it supports dragging a file from one computer to another.  Its probably the one I'd recommend as I have used both at work where I have a single keyboard/mouse I use for both a windows & mac machine

[Synergy](http://synergy-project.org) is less advanced but costs less money and also will run over UDP & TCP which allows you to tunnel it though networks

Synergy can also be obtained for free if you want NO support by getting the nightly build at:  https://synergy-project.org/nightly

These programs will also allow you to MIX operating system so you can share 1 mouse/keyboard between a Windows Desktop and a Mac Laptop for instance.

### Summary

- ShareMouse - Costs more but is easier to use and more advanced
- Synergy - Costs less / free - harder to setup and limited to 1 "control" keyboard/mouse

Comment: ShareMouse has a free version for just 2 screens. http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/freeware.htm

Answer (score 0):

BTT Remote Looks a good solution! : http://www.bttremote.com
"is a great universal iPhone/iPad app which allows you to remote control your Mac..."

I was looking for the Built-In Trackpad feature (but it has other ones):
"The trackpad is an important part of the BTT Remote. It supports inertial two finger scrolling , and even inertial cursor movement (which allows you to move the cursor fluidly over long distances with just a little swipe)"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried BTT Remote, but HippoRemote works well for me: http://hipporemote.com